# Google Tag Manager sends integer instead of decimal

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

During development a tracking system in my application I faced with a problem.
I configured GoogleTagManager layer like that (see the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ1St.png)):

[image: GTM configuration]

I configured my GA account like that (see the screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuaA5.png)):

[image: Google Analytics configuration]

When I push datalayer, I put ecommerce param:

```
"price"
```

Value as 11.24d for example. This built-in variable works just fine:
In tracking log I see

```
pr1pr=11.24
```

But if I send the same value as custom metric:

```
"metric1", 11.24
```

It will be sent like that:

```
pr1cm1=11
```

It will be transformed to integer.
Also, when I sent string, it says me that it can't be converted to integer, but the "price" built-in param can obtain even.

```
"11.24"
```

Could anyone tell me what went wrong, or where is error? For our iOS team everything works just fine. Maybe it some bug of Android implementation of gtm/ga?

[image: Google Analytics configuration]

Comment: The problem may be on your code side can you show the code?

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you fix it?

Comment: No. Get rid of google stuff